# ¿Cómo hacer un intervalo de fecha para una boleta ?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Quiero hacer un intervalo de fechas para una boleta de pagos, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

Aqui tengo la captura de como debe ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y que intentaste hasta el momento? en php o js? son dos cosas distintas.. como vienen tus datos?

Comment: Bueno puede ser en javascript de preferencia los datos los traigo con php en tipo JSON

Comment: Tienes que agregar tu codigo para poder ayudarte

Comment: no sabemos que datos tienes, no podemos ayudarte. Si tienes las 2 fechas, solo escribelas, si tienes timestamp tienes que convertirlas, si tienes una fecha y una cantidad de dias, puedes suar date en php, etc.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Nos ayudaría mucho si agregas el código con lo que has intentado hasta ahora. Te sugeriría realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) que explica como utilizar el sitio así puedes sacar el mayor provecho de esta comunidad. Un saludo!